# Spring Kafka with Confluent Kafka Avro Deserializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to use Spring Kafka with Confluent schema registry and Kafka Avro Deserializer. However there is no such thing in the Spring Kafka document.

Following is what I do for my Spring Kafka consumer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfiguration {

  @Bean
  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Customer> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Customer> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, Customer> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");
    props.put("specific.avro.reader", "true");

//    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false"); // disable auto commit of offsets
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "100"); // disable auto commit of offsets
    return props;
  }
}
```

and

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumerService {

  private CustomerConverter customerConverter;

  public KafkaConsumerService(CustomerConverter customerConverter) {
    this.customerConverter = customerConverter;
  }

  @KafkaListener(id = "demo-consumer-1st-group", topics = "kafka-demo-avro")
  public void process(@Payload Customer customer,
                      @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                      @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) List<String> topics,
                      @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets) {
    LOGGER.info("topic: {}, partition: {}, offset: {}", topics.get(0), partitions.get(0), offsets.get(0));
    CustomerModel customerModel = customerConverter.convertToModel(customer);
    LOGGER.info("customer: {}", customerModel);
  }
}
```

My producer can produce Avro message successfully without any problem. But the error I got for consumer is:

```
Method [public void kafkademo.kafka.KafkaConsumerService.process(kafkademo.generated.avro.Customer)]
Bean [kafkademo.kafka.KafkaConsumerService@238258a0]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [kafkademo.generated.avro.Customer] to [kafkademo.generated.avro.Customer] for GenericMessage [payload={"id": 7, "key": "key-789", "name": "kafka"}, headers={kafka_offset=6, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7e280b0e, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=key-789, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=kafka-demo-avro, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1562593667254}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"id": 7, "key": "key-789", "name": "kafka"}, headers={kafka_offset=6, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7e280b0e, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=key-789, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=kafka-demo-avro, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1562593667254}]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [kafkademo.generated.avro.Customer] to [kafkademo.generated.avro.Customer] for GenericMessage [payload={"id": 7, "key": "key-789", "name": "kafka"}, headers={kafka_offset=6, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7e280b0e, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=key-789, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=kafka-demo-avro, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1562593667254}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"id": 7, "key": "key-789", "name": "kafka"}, headers={kafka_offset=6, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7e280b0e, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=key-789, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=kafka-demo-avro, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1562593667254}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1324) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1313) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1229) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1200) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1120) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:935) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:751) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:700) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [kafkademo.generated.avro.Customer] to [kafkademo.generated.avro.Customer] for GenericMessage [payload={"id": 7, "key": "key-789", "name": "kafka"}, headers={kafka_offset=6, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7e280b0e, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=key-789, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=kafka-demo-avro, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1562593667254}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"id": 7, "key": "key-789", "name": "kafka"}, headers={kafka_offset=6, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7e280b0e, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=key-789, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=kafka-demo-avro, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1562593667254}]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:292) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:79) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:50) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1275) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1258) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1219) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

> However there is no such thing in the Spring Kafka document.

There is nothing to document; it's just another serializer/deserializer.

> Cannot convert from [kafkademo.generated.avro.Customer] to [kafkademo.generated.avro.Customer] for ...

This looks like some kind of class loader issue.

Try using this instead

```java
  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    KafkaAvroDeserializer avroDeser = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();
    avroDeser.configure(consumerConfigs(), false);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), 
                   new StringDeserializer(), 
                   avroDeser);
  }
```

so that the listener and deserializer are created in the same class loader.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your reply. So what is `myConfiguredAvroDeserializer`? Do I need to create this? I am thinking to use the default `KafkaAvroDeserializer` which provides by Confluent. I used the same for producer.

Comment: Yes, you will need to configure it (schema registry etc) instead of via the consumer properties. You can call `configure()` passing in the properties.

Comment: Can you please show me an example by using confluent's `KafkaAvroDeserializer`?

Comment: The compile can't passed given `<>` can't infer arguments. Even I remove `<>` and run the consumer still same issues. It's quite weird.

Comment: Try `public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {`.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what your runtime environment is. I can't reproduce the issue with a stand alone application.

Comment: Is it possible to have to have `MyAvroDataClass` as type parameter instead of `Object`? I tried, but the IDE shows: `Con not infer type arguments`, e.g.: `@Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, MyCustomData> yetAnotherProducerFactory() {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, MyCustomData> x = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(
                myAvroProducerConfig(),
                StringSerializer::new,
                KafkaAvroSerializer::new);
        return x;
    }`

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments; it doesn't help other people finding answers. No; because `KafkaAvroSerializer` is not generic; it `implements Serializer<Object>`.  Why do you need it defined that way? (don't answer here - ask a new question).